# How can I implement a recursive reverseSubList function in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Trying to implement a function that reverses a sub-list recursively.

I have code that reverses a list recursively:

```
def recur_reverse(list1):
    if len(list1) <= 1:
        return list1

    return recur_reverse(list1[1:]) + [list1[0]]
```

And code that makes a new list given step value and initial position/index:

```
def newList(list1, step, posn):
    return list1[posn::step]
```

I have tried combining these two together but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Reiterating, I want to be able to have a list say [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], provide a step value say 2, and initial position say 1. So the sub-list would be [2, 4, 6] and after reversing it, the sub-list would be [6, 4, 2].

So far, what I have is the following:

```
def revSubList(list1, step, posn):
    if len(list1) <= 1:
        return list1

    return revSubList(list1[posn-1::step-1], step, posn) + [list1[0]]
```

When I print this resulting list, it's [6, 1] but I need [6, 4, 2]. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is it a toy problem to practice your recursive coding or you actually just need the result? Because simply `list[pos::step][::-1]` should work...

Answer (score 0):

Your indices are just wrong. And why decrementing `step`? After you extracted `L[pos]` you need to recursively work on `L[pos+step:]` but in that slice the initial position should be `0`.

```
def revSubList(L, step, pos):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    return revSubList(L[pos+step:], step, 0) + [L[pos]]
```